# Lua: delete last {..}

Tags: string, lua, pattern-matching

In a string like `{any {possible} characters}{anything}` I want to delete the *last* `{...}` occurrence, which itself can *not* include another `{...}` combination. No problem with searching the last `{` and then using `string.sub`. 
However is there a short command with pattern matching which strips the last one like:

```
str = "{any {possible} characters}{anything}"
print(str:gmatch(...))
```

should write `{any {possible} characters}`

Comment: What would be the result for `"{anything}{any {possible} characters}"`?

Comment: that one is not possible in my case. But anyway, it should return "{anything}"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two possible solutions.

No nested braces at the end:

```
string.gsub('{any {possible} characters}{anything}', '{[^{}]*}$', '')
```

Here, `{[^{}]*}$` matches a `{`, then any 0+ chars other than `{` and `}`, and then a `}` char that must be at the end of the string (`$`).

If there are nested braces at the end use the following:

```
string.gsub('{anything}{any {possible} characters}', '%b{}$', '')
```

Here, `%b{}$` matches a `{...}` substring with any amount of nested braces inside and then asserts the position at the end of the string with `$`.

See [this Lua demo](https://ideone.com/cB1HfA)

Note that you may add `%s*` to match any 0+ whitespaces (it is useful if there is trailing whitespace, e.g.) - `'%b{}%s*$'`.